# Rails production server fails because it calls a script that shouldn't be called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails project that is working fine in development mode but when I run `rails s -e production` it fails with

```
/home/dgriffith/codem-schedule/app/workers/combine.rb:7:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `casecmp' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
...(I can post the rest if needed)...
```

This error makes since if `combine.rb` is being run but it should be.

`combine.rb`:

```
uploadDir = ARGV.shift
uploadName = ARGV.shift
fileExtension = ARGV.shift

require 'pubnub'

if fileExtension.casecmp("MTS") == 0
....
end
```

This is a worker that I call from my controller when something is posted to it. I call it like this:

```
pid = spawn("ruby #{Rails.root.join('app','workers', 'reconstructUploads.rb')} #{Rails.root.to_s} #{params[:fileName]} #{params[:uploadName]} #{params[:numberOfFiles]}")
Process.detach(pid)
```

This should really matter because it isn't getting executed. The script is being run by the server.

Like I said, this all works just fine in development mode. The script will not work without the params being sent in but that should never be the case because the only thing that should call it is the controller.

I have made the worker on my own and I don't know how Rails intends them to be handled. I also made the workers directory under `app`. I couldn't find anything anywhere telling me this is a bad idea.

This is all it says before exiting with the error above:

```
dustingriffith:project/ (branch*) $ rails s -e production
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.16 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
Exiting
```

Why is this script being executed? How do I prevent it from throwing an error?

Comment: The worker is used to reconstruct an upload that is sent in chunks. It takes a while to execute so instead of waiting until it is done and timing out we call the ruby script that does the magic them notifies the client with pubnub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When rails server is started, all of the code is being run to create necessary classes, modules, etc.

So your worker file is called, too, and it throws an error.

This problem appears only in production mode, because in development rails enables lazy loading of your files to support automatic update of files that are being changed while server is running.

I think, you can move your file to lib folder and run as you want. It should do the trick, because lib folder is not being loaded automatically by rails at startup time.

Comment: In development it enables lazy loading of your files to support automatic update of files that are being changed while server is running. First of all, you should find the problem and solve it :)

Comment: I think, you can move your file to lib folder and run as you want. It should do the trick.

Comment: I was just waiting on the edit. :) Thank you sir. (I am deleting the now pointless comments.)